# How to use mapply with sets of inputs of unequal lengths, using combinations of arguments?

Tags: r, function, iteration, apply, repeat

I am trying to find a way to run multiple simulations using a custom function.
Each simulation uses different input values, based on real-life measurements.
Let's say this function predicts the yield of a field crop.

```
predict <- function(input1, input2, input3){
   output = input1 + input2 + input3
   return(output)
   }
```

I know how to use *mapply* to run this function over lists of arguments, but I cannot find how to use different combinations of inputs (lists of unequal lengths).
To illustrate, I have a dataframe (with dummy numbers), with each row corresponding to a farm, each column corresponding to an input argument (apart from the first, which is the farm code).

```
df <- data.frame("Farm" = 1:3, "input1" = c(10, 20 , 30), "input2" = c(100, 200, 300))
df
```

Now, as you have noticed, I don't have the third argument "input3" in this dataframe.
For this particular argument, I have 1000 different possible values.

```
all_possible_input3 <- seq(1:1000) # dummy values
```

I want to run the predict function for each combination between the observed farm parameters and the 1000 different possible values.
To show a few examples of the first combinations, each individual would look like this:

```
# For Farm 1:
Farm1_run1 <- predict(input1 = 10, input2 = 100, input3 = 1)
Farm1_run2 <- predict(input1 = 10, input2 = 100, input3 = 2)
Farm1_run3 <- predict(input1 = 10, input2 = 100, input3 = 3)
# ... and goes on to use the 1000 values for the third argument.

# For Farm 2:
Farm2_run1 <- predict(input1 = 20, input2 = 200, input3 = 1)
Farm2_run2 <- predict(input1 = 20, input2 = 200, input3 = 2)
Farm2_run3 <- predict(input1 = 20, input2 = 200, input3 = 3)
# ... and goes on to use the 1000 values for the third argument.

# For Farm 3:
Farm3_run1 <- predict(input1 = 30, input2 = 300, input3 = 1)
Farm3_run2 <- predict(input1 = 30, input2 = 300, input3 = 2)
Farm3_run3 <- predict(input1 = 30, input2 = 300, input3 = 3)
# ... and goes on to use the 1000 values for the third argument.
```

In total, that should produce 3000 runs, corresponding to all combinations between the 3 farms and the 1000 possible input3.

I know how to use mapply to loop a function over multiple lists of arguments, but how to deal with lists of unequal lengths?
I was think of layering another *apply* function over a first one, but I have not yet found a solution.
Perhaps splitting first the dataframe, then combining each row to each possible *input3*, and then apply the function to each row of inputs?
I hope my example is clear enough...
Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track by considering a second apply. You could e.g. nest your `mapply` inside a `lapply` which loops over your `all_possible_input3`:

```r
predict <- function(input1, input2, input3){
  output = input1 + input2 + input3
  return(output)
}

df <- data.frame("Farm" = 1:3, "input1" = c(10, 20 , 30), "input2" = c(100, 200, 300))
df
#>   Farm input1 input2
#> 1    1     10    100
#> 2    2     20    200
#> 3    3     30    300

all_possible_input3 <- 1:10

farm_runs <- lapply(all_possible_input3, function(input3) {
  mapply(predict, input1 = df$input1, input2 = df$input2, input3 = input3)
})
farm_runs
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 111 221 331
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 112 222 332
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 113 223 333
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] 114 224 334
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] 115 225 335
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [1] 116 226 336
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> [1] 117 227 337
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> [1] 118 228 338
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> [1] 119 229 339
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> [1] 120 230 340
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

There is a concise way to do this using `outer` which applies `FUN` crosswise on its arguments. Just `Vectorize` the skeleton of your function call and put it into `outer` like so:

```
FUN <- Vectorize(function(i, j) with(df, my_pred(input1[i], input2[i], a.input3[j])))
res1 <- outer(1:nrow(df), seq(a.input3), FUN)
res1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]  111  112  113  114  115  116  117  118  119   120
# [2,]  221  222  223  224  225  226  227  228  229   230
# [3,]  331  332  333  334  335  336  337  338  339   340
```

---

*Data:*

```
my_pred <- function(input1, input2, input3) {  ## renamed because `predict` is actually used
  output <- input1 + input2 + input3
  return(output)
}

df <- structure(list(Farm = 1:3, input1 = c(10, 20, 30), input2 = c(100, 
200, 300)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

a.input3 <- seq(1:10)  ## shortened for example
```