# How to extract information from data nested in a multi-level list?

Tags: r, list, loops, nested, iteration

I am trying to extract data from a complicated list resulting from a `mapply` nested in a `lapply`.
The purpose was to generate model simulations with different combinations of inputs.
See other this post if that can help: [How to use mapply with sets of inputs of unequal lengths, using combinations of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66246866/11719789).

The output is a list which looks like this:

```
> output
[[1]]
              [,1]      [,2]      [,3]           
Variable1     Numeric,2 Numeric,5 Numeric,7
Variable2     Integer,2 Integer,5 Integer,7

[[2]]
              [,1]      [,2]      [,3]           
Variable1     Numeric,2 Numeric,5 Numeric,7
Variable2     Integer,2 Integer,5 Integer,7
...
```

This structure is repeated *n* times in the list, as many times as the `lapply` requested it.
I would like to extract the **last** value of `Variable1`, for each column (`[,1]`, `[,2]`, `[,3]`) from each element (`[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, `[[3]]`, etc.).

Ideally, the output would be a dataframe in long format, with the list levels and variable name accompanying the extracted value:

```
List_index    Column    Last_value_Variable1
[[1]]         [,1]      5
[[1]]         [,2]      2
[[1]]         [,3]      7
[[2]]         [,1]      8
[[2]]         [,2]      1
[[2]]         [,3]      9
...           ...     ...
```

The list indices and variable names can be renamed if necessary.
I'm not sure what sort of object I am dealing with (a list, but nested list inside..., and a bit different...).
I know how to access manually the last element at the lower level (code below), but not how to iterate the process.

```
> output[[1]][,1]$Variable1[-1]
5
> output[[2]][,3]$Variable1[-1]
9
```

Using `dput` on `output` return a something like this (simplified because the actual one is too long):

```
structure(list(
   c(1, 2), c(80L, 80L), c(2.2, 20.3),
   c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L), c(1.7, 15.9, 24.4, 30.5, 35.2),
   c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), c(1.7, 15.9, 24.4, 30.5, 35.2, 39.1, 42.4)),
   #[rest of the list removed for clarity because it's too long]
   .Dim = c(16L, 11L),
   .Dimnames = list(c("Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable5", "Variable6", "Variable7", "Variable8", "Variable9", "Variable10", "Variable11", "Variable12", "Variable13", "Variable14", "Variable15", "Variable16"),
   NULL))
```

The model is a function that returns a dataframe with 16 variables and a variable number of observations corresponding to one of the model inputs. The model was tested with a set of 11 parameter inputs (hence the `.Dim = c(16L, 11L)` in the `dput()` above).

I needed to run simulations for combinations of different inputs.
The first level of the list (`[[i]]`) corresponds to one range of parameter inputs (fed into the `lapply` function), and the second level (`[,j]`) corresponds to another set of parameters fed into the `mapply` function (in this case 11).

Comment: Can you provide a data example with `dput()`? It makes it much eaiser to write an answer.

Comment: Unfortunatly, I get an error when I try to create your object `Error in attributes(.Data) <- c(attributes(.Data), attrib) : dims [product 176] do not match the length of object [9]`

Comment: It's possible `unnest_longer()` from tidyr package could be very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking (as the data was not provided), this should work well:

```
sapply(output, function(x) x[,1]$Variable1[-1])
```

Lists can be complicated (and yours looks like it is) and what you did when extracting one value is, in my opinion, the correct first step. Then you only have to think how to write a function to access this element and put it in another *apply loop to let it work on each element of the list.

On a side note, I would probably use `purrr::map_int()` nowadays as it makes sure what you get from each iteration is a single integer values.

Comment: Thank you @JBGruber for your answer and encouragement. I think you are putting me on a good track with the `sapply`. I am new to programming but it seems odd that accessing elements of nested lists is so complicated! I have added an excerpt of the data using `dput()` if that can help...

Comment: Lists are incredibly flexible but also sometimes a bit dumb to work with. Notably, the whole tidyverse is based around the idea to use only `data.frames` where possible to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion of @JCGruber helped me find a solution.
I wrapped a `for` loop around the `sapply` to repeat the extraction process to each sub-element of the list (in my case 11).

```
l <- list()
for (i in 1:11)){
  l[i] <- as.data.frame(sapply(output, function(x) tail(x[,i]$Variable1, 1)), 4)
}
> l
[[1]]
[1]  0.8794 23.7201 46.5609

[[2]]
[1]  5.4517 25.7046 45.9574

[[3]]
[1]  8.6468 26.0620 43.4773

[[4]]
[1] 25.3687 40.9850 56.6014

[[5]]
[1] 28.9796 41.0070 53.0343

[[6]]
[1]  0.913 23.699 46.485

[[7]]
[1] 34.3093 45.8173 57.3253

[[8]]
[1] 30.9206 42.1212 53.3218

[[9]]
[1]  0.9130 22.4922 44.0714

[[10]]
[1] 44.4389 57.3425 70.2460

[[11]]
[1] 57.3268 67.5774 77.8280
```

We can find the 11 elements of the list, with the 3 last values of each sub-list, obtained from the variable I was interested in (variable1). Sorry if the exact values do not correspond in this example. Ultimately the position of each list element is what matters the most.
It is now much is easier to wrangle the data.
Thank you again @JCGruber for putting me on a good track.